# TestDisk doesn't find the right Ext4 partition

Tags: linux, partitioning, data-recovery, partition-recovery, testdisk

**Situation**:

I have a hard disk that originally had some NTFS partitions and an Ext4 partition (besides some unallocated space and a Linux Swap). It lost its partition table. Nothing has been overwritten.

**Background**:

Once upon a time, I bought a Seagate external hard drive and I suspected it was defective, because transfer rates would randomly become extremely low. Before sending it to warranty, I tried to run a diagnostic tool on it (made available by Seagate at [seagate.com/support/warranty-and-replacements](http://www.seagate.com/support/warranty-and-replacements)). Running the short test command, it returned a not-helpful error message. Tried a couple other times, same thing. Then I decided to run it on a partition of my internal drive to see if the error would persist. Bad idea. Immediately, I couldn't access any file on the computer. I turned the computer off, and when I turned it back on, the internal hard disk had become a gloomy valley of emptiness.

**Accomplishes**:

TestDisk shows all the NTFS partitions missing and I can see all the directories and files belonging to them.

**Problem**:

For the Ext4 partition (where Ubuntu used to inhabit), it doesn't show any files. Instead, it shows the frightening message “*No file found, filesystem may be damaged.*” If I choose to write the partition anyway, it cannot be mounted and cannot be restored with e2fsck even with [alternative superblocks](https://linuxexpresso.wordpress.com/2010/03/31/repair-a-broken-ext4-superblock-in-ubuntu/).

**Goal**:

Have TestDisk find the right Ext4 partition with all its files; or

Find a way to fix the wrong partition written by TestDisk.

**Questions**:

1) Anything else I could try?

2) What could cause TestDisk to find files to all partitions except for this Ext4?

**Remarks**:

- The Ext4 partition was not encrypted.
- After writing the (wrong) Ext4 partition with TestDisk, I'm able to recover (apparently) all of its files with [R-Linux] and [PhotoRec].
- TestDisk mistakenly shows multiple Linux partitions (where there's actually only one), each beginning and ending at different points, overlapping one other. I have tried the one that starts first, the one that ends last, and some in between.
- I had TestDisk deep scan the disk using the Intel partition table type. I also tried EFI GPT (as suggested by the tool), but this one didn't even find the Ubuntu partition.
- When I run TestDisk with the default number of heads (255), it suggests the correct number may be 128. But when I try 128, all the NTFS partitions complain they are actually 255.
- TestDisk says right after the analysis: “*The harddisk (1000 GB / 931 GiB) seems too small! (< 3058511 TB / 2781700 TiB). Check the harddisk size: HD jumpers settings, BIOS detection…*”
- When opening GParted, I get the message “*The driver descriptor says the physical block size is 2048 bytes, but Linux says it is 512 bytes.*”
- I'm running Ubuntu via a USB drive to run these tools.
- I'm working on a copy of the disk (made with dd).
- I have a backup of the important files, so I'm not desperate. But I really wish I could restore the disk.